# Unexpected numpy image reshape into grid problem

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to reshape a numpy array image into a grid image of 16x16 elements per cell. I think that

```
grid_image = image.reshape((h//16, w//16, -1))
```

should do the trick. In the example below grid_image has a (1, 2, 256) shape. However, when I compare elements  grid_image[0,0] with the elements in image[:16, :16].ravel() they are not the same. The code below prints False. My logic must be wrong but I don't know where. any help?

```
import numpy as np
h,w = 16,32
image = np.random.rand(h, w)
grid_image = image.reshape((h//16, w//16, -1))                  
print((image[:16, :16].ravel() == grid_image[0,0]).all())
```

Comment: Look at `np.arange(16).reshape(4,4).reshape(2,2,-1)`. Does the last reshape do anything like what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some additional transposing. Here is how I think about it:

Let `x` and `y` be the height and width of the cell, both 16 in this case.
Let `rows = h // x` and `cols = w // y` be the number of patches in each direction.

- Image shape / ordering currently: `(rows x) (cols y)`
- Your desired array shape: `rows cols (x y)`

So `cols` and `x` need to swap axes.

```
x = y = 16
rows, cols = h // x, w // y
grid_image = image.reshape(rows, x, cols, y).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(rows, cols, x * y)
```